# How do you add [NSArray arrayWithObjects NSNumber numberWithInt:] with text string?

Tags: xcode, text, nsarray, nsnumber

How do I add text in NSNumber? I can't find solution to fix this problem. How do you this?

```
NSString *myInt = interestRate.text;

NSArray *vals = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                 [NSNumber numberWithInt:30],
                 [NSNumber numberWithInt: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", myInt]],
                 [NSNumber numberWithInt:20],
                 [NSNumber numberWithInt:56],
                 [NSNumber numberWithInt:70],
                 [NSNumber numberWithInt:34],
                 [NSNumber numberWithInt:43],
                 nil];
```

I'm having trouble adding text each one of them.

Comment: check my answer, I have updated `integerValue` to `intValue` to remove a warning.

Comment: And if it solves kindly accept or inform me

Comment: +1 for you :) So you get an upvote privilege :)

Comment: You can't put a string into a number (NSNumber in this case), that just doesn't make sense. Strings and numbers are just completely different things.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
NSString *myInt = interestRate.text;

NSArray *vals = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                 [NSNumber numberWithInt:30],
                 [NSNumber numberWithInt:[myInt intValue]],
                 [NSNumber numberWithInt:20],
                 [NSNumber numberWithInt:56],
                 [NSNumber numberWithInt:70],
                 [NSNumber numberWithInt:34],
                 [NSNumber numberWithInt:43],
                 nil];
```